# How to make Alert work on android/emulator? (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, alert

my package.json

Trying to run on expo cli with expo start -c. Usual alert() works, but not Alert from react-native

{
      "name": "my-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.1",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "json-server": "^0.16.1",
        "react": "^16.12.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "server": "json-server -p3001 db.json"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details about the issue. I tried an example of alert example given in below mentioned url, in an app created from expo and it worked.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert